# Cross origin Blocked after socket.io update to version 1.3.3

Tags: socket.io, socket.io-1.0

After the upgrade from socket.io version 1.1.0 to 1.3.3 the client side throws following error.

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading
>   the remote resource at
>   http://localhost/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1423291738055-2.
>   This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or
>   enabling CORS.

---

The server listens on port 3000.
Changing the policy origin settings in the server side to

```
io.set('origins', '*:*');
```

did not solve the problem.

The following change on the client side worked

```
var socket = io.connect('http://' + window.location.hostname + ":3000");
```

But on firefox the following errors are shown occasionally.

> The connection to
>   ws://localhost:3000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=qwl7Kr_--vqJP5RwAAAN
>   was interrupted while the page was loading.

---

> Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at
>   ws://localhost:3000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=BHt0QgBBauhb4WCUAAAE.

---

How to fix this issue?